# UItextView text hidden

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uitextview

I am notes.app like app. I am setting UITextView's contentInset as

```
myTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 25, 0, -25);
myTextView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(295, myTextView.contentSize.height);
```

but that does not seems to work as I expected. Two characters are hidden.

I get this [image: got this]

but if I set

```
myTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 25, 0, 0);
myTextView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(295, myTextView.contentSize.height);
```

I get actual text as

[image: required]

please help.

Answer (score 1):

fibnochi you can use a different approach to do this. I have used this in one of my app and it is working fine

First of all you need to get the size of UItextView which will carry all the data, for this you need to use NSString class delegate function

```
NSString* str = @"Your Entire string will come here";

CGSize size = [str sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0] constrainedToSize:CGSize(295, any large digit for maximum height say 10000) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

textView.contentSize = size;
```

Will this solve your problem or not. Please let me know

Comment: Fibnaochi you also need to give your UITextView a font size as 
[textView setFont:[UIFont systemFontSize:17]];
hope this will work for you

Comment: I am giving it a custom font and have calculated size using that font.Now I have reduced vertical lines distance from horizontal so that default (8,8) inset of UITextView is maintained. Though it is working but I would like to have answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the below?

```
myTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 25, 0, 25);
myTextView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(295, myTextView.contentSize.height);
```

Comment: I do not want horizontal scrolling. If I set these values. textview starts horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's discussions 
[here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html).

"
Edge inset values are applied to a rectangle to shrink or expand the area represented by that rectangle. Typically, edge insets are used during view layout to modify the view’s frame. Positive values cause the frame to be inset (or shrunk) by the specified amount. Negative values cause the frame to be outset (or expanded) by the specified amount.
"
You can do like **UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,25,0,25**)

Comment: I do not want horizontal scrolling. If I set these values. textview starts horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :)

```
myTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 25, 0, -25);
myTextView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(270, myTextView.contentSize.height);
```

May this will help you out :)